# How to generate random number within range (-x,x)

Tags: c++, random

Hi
It is possible to generate random number within a range (-x,x) using rand()?? If not, how can I generate random number withing that range ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random integer from a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range)

Answer (score 5):

```
// return a random number between 0 and limit inclusive.
int rand_lim(int limit) {

    int divisor = RAND_MAX/(limit+1);
    int retval;

    do { 
        retval = rand() / divisor;
    } while (retval > limit);

    return retval;
}

// Return a random number between lower and upper inclusive.
int rand_lim(int lower, int upper) {
    int range = abs(upper-lower);

    return rand_lim(range) + lower;
}
```

As usual, all the others I've seen in this thread can/will produce at least slightly skewed results.

Comment: Alas, this might return skewed results as well, although it will  probably not be by very much. The first `RAND_MAX%(limit+1)` numbers will be favored if `RAND_MAX%(limit+1) < limit`.

Comment: To chip in on the *skewed* bit. Let's suppose that `rand()` generates an integer in `[0..15]` with perfect uniformity, and say we want to generate a random integer between in `[-3..3]`. The usual operation consists in *folding* `[0..15]` onto `[-3..3]`: `[0..6]` and `[7..13]` map to `[-3..3]` perfectly (ie, when `rand()` returns `1` or `8`, we output `-2`)... but what happens when `rand()` returns `14` or `15` ? If we map them to `-3` and `-2` respectively, then we have a *skewed* distribution, since it's slightly more likely to get `-3` or `-2` than any other number.

Answer (score 1):

I am just a simple Basic programmer, but I feel like I am missing the point.  The answer seems simple.  Please pardon the VB code

```
    Dim prng As New Random
    Const numEach As Integer = 100000
    Const x As Integer = 3 'generate random number within a range (-x,x) inclusive

    Dim lngth As Integer = Math.Abs(-x - x) + 1
    Dim foo(lngth - 1) As Integer 'accumualte hits here

    For z As Integer = 1 To (numEach * lngth)
        Dim n As Integer = prng.Next(lngth) 'generate number in inclusive range
        foo(n) += 1 'count it
        'n = x - n 'actual n
    Next

    Debug.WriteLine("Results")
    For z As Integer = 0 To foo.Length - 1
        Debug.WriteLine((z - x).ToString & " " & foo(z).ToString & " " & (foo(z) / numEach).ToString("n3"))
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("")
```

Typical results

```
Results
-3 99481 0.995
-2 100214 1.002
-1 100013 1.000
0 100361 1.004
1 99949 0.999
2 99755 0.998
3 100227 1.002


Results
-3 100153 1.002
-2 99917 0.999
-1 99487 0.995
0 100383 1.004
1 100177 1.002
2 99808 0.998
3 100075 1.001
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range/5009228#5009228).