# Error E0169. Exspected declaration. If statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am trying to make a Rock-Paper-Scissor game in C++ in Visual Studio.

I am trying to make the computer generated response, but when I make the `if` statements, it thinks it is an error on line 9:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string rockPaperScissor;

int computerChoiceInteger = 1 + (rand() % 3);

if (computerChoiceInteger == 1) {
    cout << "1";
}

if (computerChoiceInteger == 2) {
    cout << "2";
}

if (computerChoiceInteger == 3) {
    cout << "3";
}

int main() {
    cout << "Rock, paper or scissor?\n";
    cout << "R=Rock P=Paper S=Scissor\n";

    cin >> rockPaperScissor;

    if (rockPaperScissor == "r" || "R") {
        cout << "correct";
    }
    if (rockPaperScissor == "p" || "P") {
        cout << "correct";
    }
    if (rockPaperScissor == "s" || "S") {
        cout << "correct";
    }
}
```

I have tried to comment out the first `if` statement, but then it says there is an error on line 13.

Comment: The statements in the global space should be in a function.

Comment: Also this is wrong: `rockPaperScissor == "r" || "R"` (Doesn't do you thing it does), it should be `rockPaperScissor == "r" || rockPaperScissor == "R"`

Comment: `if (rockPaperScissor == "r" || "R")` -- In the C++ book you're using, how are `if` statements constructed when comparing two or more items?

Comment: Please refer to [some good beginners book, or basic tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?r=Saves_AllUserSaves) _@Tord_

Comment: `if (tolower(rockPaperScissor[0]) == 'r)`.  You can also use `std::transform` to convert the entire string to lower or upper case.  This will elimate half of your comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

For your main error, you cannot have logical statements (`if`, `while`, etc.) outside of a function body. You will need to move all of your `if` statements into your `main` function body.

C++ uses the `main` function as the "entry point" for your program, which means once all global variables, class definitions, and more, are settled, the `main` function will be what your program begins to execute. All the logic for your program should always be inside of a function.

Also, as others in the comments have pointed out, you cannot choose between two values in an `or` statement like you are currently doing. You need to explicitly make two comparisons. I've moved your conditional logic as well as changed your `or` statements here, as well as added some more newlines:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int computerChoiceInteger = 1 + (rand() % 3);

int main() {
    if (computerChoiceInteger == 1) {
        cout << "1\n";
    }

    if (computerChoiceInteger == 2) {
        cout << "2\n";
    }

    if (computerChoiceInteger == 3) {
        cout << "3\n";
    }

    cout << "Rock, paper or scissor?\n";
    cout << "R=Rock P=Paper S=Scissor\n";

    string rockPaperScissor;
    cin >> rockPaperScissor;

    if (rockPaperScissor == "r" || rockPaperScissor == "R") {
        cout << "correct\n";
    }

    if (rockPaperScissor == "p" || rockPaperScissor == "P") {
        cout << "correct\n";
    }

    if (rockPaperScissor == "s" || rockPaperScissor == "S") {
        cout << "correct\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As further reading, you may be interested in [Generate random number between 1 and 3 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891811/generate-random-number-between-1-and-3-in-c) to generate a more truly random choice by the computer.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is structured all wrong.

- you are missing `#include <stdlib.h>` or `#include <cstdlib>` to declare `rand()`.  It is *possible* that `<iostream>` is already including one of them internally for you, but you should not rely on that behavior.  Be explicit in the headers you want to use.
- global scope can only have declarations, not statements. Statements can only appear in function scope.
- your use of the `||` operator is incorrect.  You can't compare a variable to multiple values the way you are trying to.  You need a separate comparison for each value.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int computerChoiceInteger = 1 + (rand() % 3);
    cout << computerChoiceInteger << endl;

    cout << "Rock, paper or scissor?\n";
    cout << "R=Rock P=Paper S=Scissor\n";

    string rockPaperScissor;
    cin >> rockPaperScissor;

    if (rockPaperScissor == "r" || rockPaperScissor == "R") {
        cout << "correct";
    }
    else if (rockPaperScissor == "p" || rockPaperScissor == "P") {
        cout << "correct";
    }
    else if (rockPaperScissor == "s" || rockPaperScissor == "S") {
        cout << "correct";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the code should at least compile, so you can carry on with finishing your game logic (since what you have shown is not a complete Rock-Paper-Scissor game yet).

Comment: I recommend transforming the `rockPaperScissor` string to all lower or all upper case after the `cin` statement.  This would reduce the comparisons by half and simplify the comparisons.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews while a valid point, that would just be an optimization at this stage in the OP's development.