# how to generate random numbers which do not start from 0 ( 50 - 100) etc?

Tags: c, random, numbers

please tell me is their is any way to generate random number program in c language which generate **"50 to 100"** random number not from  **0 to 100** ???
without using **if else** condition??

Comment: Generate a random number from `0` to `50` and add `50`?

Comment: Thanks sir!! in case i want to generate random numbers between 65 to 90 so what should i do??

Comment: @Maqbool Ur Rahim Khan : Is it a joke ? You have a solution from m.buettner, can't you do a simple math yourself (90-65 = 25, so you need to generate random number between 0 and 25 and add 65)?

Comment: yupppp sorry but @a1ex07 your ans help me alot ??

Comment: @BrianRoach you are right i should learn maths first :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random integer from a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range)

Answer (score 3):

The '%' operator returns the remainder of the integer division.So if you say number%5 the value may be within 0 and 4 (included).
So rand()%51 returns a number from 0 to 50, add it 50 and you'll get what you want.
Define a macro:

```
#define RandomNumberInInterval(min,max) rand()%(max-min+1)+min
```

Comment: A couple of important notes: 1. this will produce bogus results if `max - min > RAND_MAX` 2. using the modulo operation results in a non-uniform distribution which worsens as `max - min` increases...

Comment: You should also check that the programmer has good sense.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: good sense: No such file or directory :-)

Answer (score 2):

Generate it from `0 - 50` and sum 50.

```
number = ( rand() % 51 ) + 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since you can always replace `if (foo) { ... }` by `while (foo) { ... break; }`.