# In c++ , how would i generate a random number between 2 and 14?

Tags: c++, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random integer from a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range)

I am just starting to learn `c++`, and for a class assignment i'm supposed to use `rand()` and get a random number between 2 and 14. I know to get like between 1 and 10 i would do `rand()%10+1`

In my case would I need to do  `rand()%14+2`?

I understand that others have posted similar questions, but they appear to all do between even multiples, such as 1 and 10, or 10 and 20 etc.

Comment: I'd try doing %12 instead of %14.

Comment: Do *do* know that `rand()%10+1` doesn't give **uniformly distributed** random numbers in the range between 1 and 10, right? Some integers are more likely to come out than others. The same applies to `rand()%14+2` and the variant suggested in a comment.

Comment: Please don't remove the automatically inserted duplicate link.

Answer (score 0):

rand()%12+2
notice there is a gap of 12 number in between and your lower bound is 2.

Comment: but it is encompassing 13 numbers, not 12

Comment: How did you manage to add an answer to a closed question? O.o

Comment: Its closed? I never closed it

Comment: It doesn't encompass 13 though, any number % 12 only has 12 possibilities. 12 % 12 = 0 remainder, so the possibilities are 1-11 and 0, which are 12 :D