# Generating random integer values within a range in C

Tags: c, random, numbers, integer, generator

How do I go about generating random integer values between a range (in this case 1-12 including 1 and 12) in the C language?

I've read about seeding (srand()) and using rand() within a range but am unsure about how to go about it.

Edit: Here is what I have so far

```c
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <time.h>

// Craps Program
// Written by Kane Charles
// Lab 2 - Task 2

// 7 or 11 indicates instant win
// 2, 3 or 12 indicates instant los
// 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10 on first roll becomes "the point"
// keep rolling dice until either 7 or "the point is rolled"
//      if "the point" is rolled the player wins
//      if 7 is rolled then the player loses

int wins = 0, losses = 0;
int r, i;
int N = 1, M = 12;
int randomgenerator();


main(void){

  /* initialize random seed: */
  srand (time(NULL));
  /* generate random number 10,000 times: */
  for(i=0; i < 10000 ; i++){
     int r = randomgenerator();
     if (r = 7 || 11) {
        wins++;
     }
     else if (r = 2 || 3 || 12) {
        losses++;
     }
     else if (r = 4 || 5 || 6 || 8 || 9 || 10) {
        int point = r;
        int temproll;
        do
        {
            int temproll = randomgenerator();

        }while (temproll != 7 || point);

        if (temproll = 7) {
            losses++;
        }
        else if (temproll = point) {
            wins++;
        }
     }
  }
    printf("Wins\n");
    printf("%lf",&wins);
    printf("\nLosses\n");
    printf("%lf",&losses);
}

int randomgenerator(){
    r = M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: See here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range (C++, but answers cover C as well.)

Comment: [This site](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html) might be of interest, to you...

Comment: You've accepted Chahaun's answer as correct, but note my concern about roundoff error.  His algorithm probably does not in fact uniformly sample from the range, i.e., doesn't behave correctly.

Comment: @MattPhillips I haven't really thought about it in depth yet, but what you say sounds like a useful consideration. Perhaps you should add some explanation of this to your answer?

Comment: @jogojapan Ok I added some comments.

Comment: There's no way this program is doing what you think it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use: [M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1)](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html)

Don't use `rand() % N` (which tries to return numbers from 0 to N-1). It is poor, because the low-order bits of many random number generators are distressingly non-random. ([See question 13.18.](http://c-faq.com/lib/notveryrand.html))

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
int main ()
{
  int r, i;
  int M = 1,
      N = 12;
  /* initialize random seed: */
  srand (time(NULL));

  /* generate number between 1 and 12: */
  for(i=0; i < 10 ; i++){ 
     r = M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1);
     printf("\n%d", r);
  }
  printf("\n") ;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It's working here at [codepad](http://codepad.org/zfAyc24z).

Comment: [This site](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html) might also be of interest to you, my friend...

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Thanks interesting :) Its good site. Have you gone to the site I linked in this answer.

Comment: Where the range is large, roundoff error will bias the distribution towards lower values.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue hi do you have idea on page-faults and virtual memories?

Comment: I need to produce 10,000 random numbers that can only be between 1 and 12, will this be able to do so?
EDIT: Works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: @KaneCharles Not if you care about loaded dice...

Comment: The answer is INCORRECT as N and M are mistaken. Please take Matt's concern seriously.

Comment: In regards to your line:

`srand (time(NULL));`

I'm getting the error: `/home/kane/C Programming/src/Craps.cpp|24|error: ‘time’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @Yang Not if you care about loaded dice... KaneCharles: `#include <time.h>`, as [the manual for `time`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/time.html) indicates. Having said that, I wouldn't expect a person who asks a question like this to be able to read the manual. *sigh*

Comment: I'm new to this so I'm still learning the basics. I've edited my original post with the code I am using, it is still throwing a few errors but I hope to fix them myself.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Would you like to ask a more specific question [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28070/room-for-modifiable-lvalue-and-grijesh-chauhan)?

Comment: @KaneCharles Which book are you reading?

Comment: I'm doing this from a course at uni, this is only the second week's lab so I'm just working off what the lectures have shown us. I've done Java before so some of this is familiar territory. @modifiablelvalue

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Actually, probability adjustment for uniform distribution has been concluded in the given `M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1)`. It's just that N and M are mistaken. I was just kindly recalling the comprehension behind.

Comment: @KaneCharles Disregard the similarity you believe C has to Java. In C, there is a concept known as "undefined behaviour" (research it yourself; you're a Uni student...). Code that invokes UB might appear to work on your system, but only by coincidence. It might then fail subtly or in devastating ways on other systems. Hence, you can't learn C by mashing your face on the keyboard and fixing the resulting errors like you can in Java. As a Uni student, it's important that you research (eg. reading books and manuals) independently, in your own time. I'm sure your lecturer would agree.

Comment: @Yang rand isn't required to produce uniformly distributed values. A perfectly compliant implementation of rand might produce 0 every time.

Comment: @Yang OP updated his question since I posted my answer. rand() don't produce uniformly distributed values.

Comment: @KaneCharles Trust on what you understands I posted a link at first line in my answer. read from related pages also.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timeval t1;
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    srand(t1.tv_usec * t1.tv_sec);

    int a = 1, b = 12;

    int val = a + (b-a) * (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX + 0.5;

    return 0;
}
```

Edit, since someone asked: You really do have to use floating point arithmetic to get this to come out right (or as right as it can given `rand()`'s limitations such as they are).  Any solution which relies purely on integer arithmetic and `rand()` will of necessity use `\` or `%`, and when this happens you will get roundoff error--where c and d are declared `int` and c = 5 and d = 2, for example, c/d == 2 and d/c == 0.  When comes to sampling from a range, what happens is that in compressing the range `[0, RAND_MAX]` to `[a, b]`, you have to do some kind of division operation since the former is so much larger than the latter.  Then roundoff creates bias (unless you get really lucky and things evenly divide).  Not a truly thorough explanation but I hope that conveys the idea.

Comment: Can you please how this works and why it is dirty?

Comment: @KaneCharles  `rand()` generates a number from 0 to `RAND_MAX`.  Dividing by `RAND_MAX` then gives you a random value on [0, 1] which can then be scaled according to the range of discrete values you want.  As for being dirty, actually I think I was thinking of another way this gets done sometimes with `%`--this answer is not dirty!  Edited accordingly. :)

Comment: It's dirty because it uses C++ in a C question, and because it uses rand, which just isn't all that great.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Sorry where's the C++?

Comment: @KaneCharles Note my edit, I've generalized the answer to make the parameterization by range obvious.

Comment: @MattPhillips: `#include <cstdlib>` doesn't work in a C compiler. It's a C++ header.

Comment: Thanks for taking into account my request. +1 for raising valid points. There are a few things I had to do to get this to compile, though, notably: use `struct timeval` instead of just `timeval`, and of course add `int main() { .... return 0; }`.

Comment: @jogojapan Thanks, happy to help.  I've incorporated your notes into the answer.