# c++ random number from 1 to 8 digits

Tags: c++

I'm trying to generate a random from 1 - 99,999,999
However, its not ever getting that high. I believe it has something to do with the size of an int.

Here is what I'm trying

```
(1 + rand() % 99999999)
```

Thanks

Comment: what platform/compiler?

Comment: `RAND_MAX` is most likely 32k. Use `<random>`. It's a lot better anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty sure an `int` can contain much more than that.

Comment: Apart from being a terrible formula, I don't suppose you know the value of RAND_MAX for your current implementation? Methinks thats about the limit you will see using this mechanism. (and in case you're using VC++, their 32bit RAND_MAX is only 0x7FFF, or 65535). See [<random>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) in the C++ 11 standard library, and use *that*. It's much more robust than the crap-legacy interface and manages the modulus probability balancing for you. `std::random_device` + `<<choose your engine>>` + `std::uniform_int_distribution` together do exactly what you want.

Comment: If you have access to c++11 - http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful - Don't use rand.

Answer (score 1):

your code will not work because value returned by [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) have a maximum value [RAND_MAX](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/)

> int rand (void);
>
> Generate random number
> Returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and
> RAND_MAX.

---

> RAND_MAX
>
> Maximum value returned by rand This macro expands to an
> integral constant expression whose value is the maximum value returned
> by the rand function.
>
> This value is library-dependent, but is guaranteed to be at least
> 32767 on any standard library implementation.

Comment: hence, printing out `sizeof rand()`, and `sizeof RAND_MAX` would shed some light on what platform `int` you have.

Comment: @Phlip: `sizeof RAND_MAX` will tell you exactly nothing.

Comment: @Phlip this question have nothing to do with data type size.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a random number between min and max, and they should be **long data type** use:

```
long randamNum = rand()%(max-min + 1) + min;

(Includes max and min)
```

For more clearity refer [Generating random integer from a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range)

Comment: I'll bet you `sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)` for the OP. 16-bit ints aren't that common anymore and I have yet to know of something with 64-bit one but not the other.

Comment: lol, no. An `int` can contain that number. That's not the problem.

Comment: I can't see how type `long` or even `long long` will change anything