# Getting a range off user input for random generation

Tags: java, random, integer

So I am trying to get my code to get a random number generation based off what the user inputs. and my current statement doesnt generate the proper range.

```
  secretNum = low + (int)(Math.random()* max);
```

Where low is the lowest part of the range, and high is the highest. For example. if low was 5 and high was 10, would this generate a range from 1-50? (5*10).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a [Random object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) for this.

You create it like this:

```
Random r = new Random();
```

And then from there, it is very easy to use. For a random int from 0 (inclusive) to 50 (exclusive), just do:

```
int randomNumber = r.nextInt(50);
```

I think it makes all of this much easier for you. If the user inputs 10 and 140, then you do something like this:

```
int lowest = 10;
int highest = 140;
int randomMax = 140-10;
int randomNumber = r.nextInt(randomMax) + 10;
```

It's probably the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You save your user input in the variable `in`:

```
String in = sc.nextLine();
```

Then you create a instance of `java.util.Random` with the seed being a hash of the input:

```
Random r = new Random(in.hashCode());

int randomNumber = r.nextInt();
```

*If you want to generate a random number between with a maximum and a minimum see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range)*
Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range) but then you need to convert c++ into java:

C++:

```
output = min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1))
```

Java:

```
output = min + (r.nextInt() % (max - min + 1))
```

You can also use `r.nextInt(max)` if you only need a maximum.

> Note:
>   For cryptographically secure random numbers use an instance of SecureRandom