# Can't write the output of a loop to a file

Tags: c++, ofstream, time.h

Hello Im coding a very basic password generator and I want to write the output of the loop to a file using ofstream. My idea was each time the loop runs output one vocal from the array `abc`. I don't know to to make it to work and obvs. there is a better way of doing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main(){

    srand(time(0));

    cout << "You'r PW is: \t" << endl;
    char abc [] {'A', 'a', 'B' ,'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'V', 'v', 'W', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'Z', 'z'};

    for(int i = 0; i <15; i++){
        int randomNum =  rand() % 53;
        cout << abc[randomNum];
        ofstream fob;
        fob.open("contr.txt");
        fob << abc[randomNum];
    }
}
```

By the way, I am getting characters like ',' and '->' which isn't in my array.

Comment: Don't you want mod 52 instead of mod 53?

Comment: There is no need to create an array of chars to generate random characters.

Comment: So then how do I do it?

Comment: Add `cout << sizeof(abc) << "\n";` right under where you declare the array.  Compare that number to the value you are using for mod.

Comment: Also, for a better way to generate the random numbers, see [Generating random integer from a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have to move

```
ofstream fob;
fob.open("contr.txt");
```

out of loop. Now you rewrite file on every iteration.

Comment: Indexing out of the bounds of the array is also a problem.  Assuming all of the letters were in the array the number should be 52, but there are 2 letters missing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is very simple and there are two solutions to it.
What your program does is create and open a new stream to a file every iteration of the loop, but by default the `ofstream` overwrites the files it opens so you can either move the stream opening out of the loop(the better way) or add the flag `ios::app` as a second argument to the stream opener in order to append the content you're outputting.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you should be using `int randomNum = rand() % 52;`.
to choose a number in the set {0, 1, 2, ... 51}, which will be one of all the possible indexes to your array assuming you forgot to put 'X' in your array.