# C++ random number are not changing

Tags: c++, c++11, random, gaussian

I created this method for generating random numbers in c++ , when I call it in loop, I always get the same random value, what is wrong? Because I expect different value after every loop iteration. I am compiling it with flag -std=c++11.

```
float CDevice::gaussNoise(float mean, float stddev)
{
    std::default_random_engine generator(time(NULL));
    std::normal_distribution<float> distribution(mean, stddev);
    return distribution(generator);
}
```

main looks like this:

```
int main
{
    class CDevice *device;
    device = new CDevice();
    std::vector<float> vec;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i< 10; ++i)
        vec.push_back(device->gaussNoise(1,5));
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
            std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
}
```

and output is (for example):

```
3.71254
3.71254
3.71254
3.71254
3.71254
3.71254
3.71254
3.71254
3.71254
3.71254
```

Comment: Seen this so many times here... initialize your random number generate *outside* of your loop! Generally *once* at the beginning of your application.

Comment: Topic -> 'reffer' about random number

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range

Comment: You keep asking a new, identically-configured RNG, for its first output when you want to keep asking the same RNG for its successive outputs.

Comment: I has to be a dupe of something. Googling "C++ random number are not changing" provides a bazillion (but fortunately not a googleplex) links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You reseed the random number generator with every call. Because you are calling the function continuously, `time(NULL)` likely doesn't change. You should seed once at the start of your program, probably in the constructor of `CDevice`.