# cin.getline not waiting for input and setting parameters on rand

Tags: c++

I am simply trying to get the input from the user for the name of the ski resort to display fully with white spaces. I have tried multiple things including setting a constant for size, using cin.get and cin.getline. Have had no luck thusfar. Also directly below it, I am trying to set the parameters on the rand function using information entered by user previously in minimumSnowfall and maximumSnowfall.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main(void)

{
    int minimumSnowfall;
    int maximumSnowfall;
    char skiResortName[81];


    cout << "I will forecast how much snowfall there will be on each \nday this weekend. You get to pick the range. " << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the minimum amount of snow that \nwill fall in one day in inches: ";
    cin >> minimumSnowfall;


    cout << "Please enter the maximum amount of snow that \nwill fall in one day in inches: ";
    cin >> maximumSnowfall;

    // need to fix to display names with white spaces
    cout << "Enter the name of the ski resort: ";
    cin.getline(skiResortName,81);
    cout << "The local forecast for snowfall at " << skiResortName << " this weekend: " << endl;

    // need to fix to display random number using parameters entered by weatherman in minimumSnowfall and maximumSnowfall
    cout << "Friday: " rand  (minimumSnowfall, maximumSnowfall);







    return 0;
```

Comment: Explain this line: `cout << "Friday: " rand % minimumSnowfall, maximumSnowfall);` Where is your `getline` btw?

Comment: It is not proper code. I have no idea how to set parameters using the input from the user for those two ints.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to match your question.  There's no get line in there anywhere.

Comment: @Jaeden By *"cin.getline not waiting for input and setting parameters on rand"* you mean *"how to print a random number between two values"*? Because it does not mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: @LogicStuff exactly right, between the two values inputted previously by the user in minimumSnowfall and maximumSnowfall.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range

Comment: @LogicStuff can you interpret this in simple terms? I am not a programming major and do not speak the language of programmers yet (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem of reading string input after an `int`/`long`/`float`/etc. The issue is the `'\n'` character remaining in the buffer after an integer has been read:

```
cin >> maximumSnowfall;
```

When you call `getline` the `'\n'` still remaining in the buffer gets read right away. The standard library interprets it as an empty string, and returns right away.

To avoid this issue call `ignore` after reading an `int`:

```
cin >> maximumSnowfall;
cin.ignore(1, '\n');
```