# can random C++ 2011 standard functions be called from a C routine?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, random

I need to generate a random integer from a range and have found very interesting what is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range) in the answer by `@Walter`. However, it is `C++11` standard and I need to use `C`, is there a way of making the call from C? I reproduce his answer here:

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;     // only used once to initialise (seed) engine
std::mt19937 rng(rd());    // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(min,max); // guaranteed unbiased

auto random_integer = uni(rng);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use C++ classes in C, but can wrap the C++ functionality in functions, which can be called from C, e.g. in getrandom.cxx:

```
#include <random>

static std::random_device rd;
static std::mt19937 rng(rd());
static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(min,max);

extern "C" int get_random()
{
    return uni(rng);
}
```

This is a C++ module exporting a get_random function with C linkage (that is, callable from C. You declare it in getrandom.h:

```
extern "C" int get_random();
```

and can call it from your C code.

Comment: I have written the `C++` code in a getrandom.cpp and created a getrandom.h file with the declaration. Then tried compiling `#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "getrandom.h"

int main()
{
  printf("%i\n", get_random());
}
` but it doesn't work, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @AP13 There is semicolon missing at the end of the `get_random`'s declaration. Did you already fixed that? And do you get a compiler or runtime error?

Comment: @Martin Zabel thanks, yes I finally got it. The code was compiling fine but not linking well.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to call C++ code from C code, you can wrap your code in an `extern "C"` block. The function signature must be a valid C function, and is then available to C code to call. However, the contents of the function can include whatever C++-isms you want.

See this question for more info: [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it all up in a C++ function with `extern "C"` linkage.