# mt19937 random number range - weird output 00A8106E

Tags: c++, c++11, random, range, output

I want to create a little game in c++, and therefore I need a function to return random numbers in a specific range.

Most of the answers I found were similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728404/5780938, and I think this is the solution I'm looking for.

To test if the function does, what I want it to, I tried outputting the results in several different ways.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <random>


int zufälligeZahl();

int main()
{
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

cout << zufälligeZahl << "\n";
cout << zufälligeZahl << "\n";
cout << zufälligeZahl << "\n";
cout << zufälligeZahl << "\n";

return 0;
}

int zufälligeZahl()
{
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 zGenerator(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(1, 13);

int random_integer = uni(zGenerator); 

return random_integer; 
}
```

I've tried this in many different ways, but no matter what I do, it doesn't work. Either the output is something like 00A8106E, or I don't get any output at all.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the function `zufälligeZahl`, you are printing out the address of the function. 
Fix your code by actually calling the function:

```
 cout << zufälligeZahl() << "\n";
```

You forgot the parentheses.

Comment: Oh, damn, that was a stupid mistake :(. The weird thing is, that I actually tried copying solutions from different websites, and it still didn't work. I guess that got me even more confused. Thank you very much for your answer!