# Generation of random number(within a limit) code overshooting the upper limit

Tags: c++, random

My Computer science C++ book says that to generate random numbers with a lower limit (in this case, 15)and upper limit(in this case, 50), we have to use the following code. But when I used it I got the output as 56,32,49,15. Is there a reason why the program is giving results that overshoot the upper limit or is the code wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){
int i,rdno;
for(i=1;i<5;++i){
        rdno=(rand()%50)+15;
    cout <<rdno<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you are generating numbers in the range `[15;15+50)` (`[15;65)`).

Comment: Not your problem, but the 1st declaration of `i` is unnecessary.

Comment: It's disturbing how many people rushed to answer this just now and still got it wrong, heh.

Comment: You really need to get a [better book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: What book is that, so I can tell students to avoid it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to generate a number in [a;b) use

```
rdno = rand() % (b-a) + a
```

Answer (score 2):

Here: `rdno = (rand()%50)` you assign a pseudo-random number from 0-49. If you add 15, you get numbers from 15 to 64. If you want the numbers from 15 to 50, you can do it for example like this: `rdno = (rand()%36) + 15`.

EDIT: You need to use `%36`, as the highest number you want is 50. You can get it, when `rand()` generates 35, then `35%36` equals 35, and 35+15 equals 50. If you used `%35`, the highest number you can get is 49.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to generate a random number in C that is between [x, y] such that y < 32768 is the following:

```
int random(int low, int high) {
    return rand() % (high - low + 1) + low;
}
```

Notice the +1 at the modulus operator, this is to allow inclusion of 50. Without it, your range becomes [15, 50).

Sample run: http://ideone.com/Q6l0e5

For a C++ solution, please look at this: [std::unfirom_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Answer (score 1):

Because the result of `rand() % 50` is added to 15. So your range is 15-65.
Your range really is 35 (or 36 if inclusive) so you could change it to:

```
15 + (rand() % 35)
```

But really though, if you have access to C++11 use [`<random>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728404/1870760):

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 rng(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(15, 50);

int random_integer = dis(rng);
```

Comment: That's not true, you can never get number 50 with your code, as 35%35 equals 0.

Comment: @HonzaDejdar "*(or 36 if inclusive)*". If OP wants 50 the range is 36.