# Why the static_cast on time(0) on this code

Tags: c++

I'm currently reading a beginner book on C++ and it has this example:

```
int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); //seed random number generator
    int randomNumber = rand(); //generate random number
    int die = (randomNumber % 6) + 1; // get a number between 1 and 6
    cout << "You rolled a " << die << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I just want to know the purpose of the cast. I tried

```
cout << time(0);
```

and

```
cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0));
```

it produces the same result so I'm not sure why the cast in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type returned by `std::time` which `std::time_t` is an implementation defined numeric type.

Numeric types are implicitly convertible to each other, so `srand(time(0));` is guaranteed to be well defined, but on some implementation, `std::time_t` could be a type whose all values are not representable by `unsigned int`, so a helpful compiler might produce a warning about a narrowing conversion that might be have been accidental.

The explicit static cast tells the compiler that a conversion is intentional, so no warning would be produced regardless of how `std::time_t` is defind.

Answer (score 4):

[`srand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) expects an `unsigned int` and [`time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) returns `std::time_t` which is an implementation defined type. It might not be `unsigned` but signed. The `static_cast` is there to suppress the possibility of an error/warning if `std::time_t` is defined as something else as `unsigned int`. Note that this isn't actually good practice.

P.S If you have a compiler that supports C++11 then stop using `rand()/srand()` all together and start using the new header [`<random>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728404/1870760).

Comment: Would you like to explain why suppressing the warning(in this case) isn't good practise?

Comment: @MartinBonner Whoops, I was referring to the way of generating those numbers. Not the cast itself. Now having re-read my answer it doesn't sound like that. Thanks.