# rand() in range returning numbers outside of the range

Tags: math

In my program, I have to find two random values with certain conditions:

`i` needs to be int range `[2...n]`

`k` needs to be in range `[i+2...n]`

so I did this:

```
i = rand() % n + 2;
k = rand() % n + (i+2);
```

But it keeps giving me wrong values like

for `n = 7`

I get `i = 4` and `k = 11`

or `i = 3` and `k = 8`

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's a simple math. `rand() % n + 2` will give you `[0..n-1] + 2 = [2..n+1]`. I trust you can make it from here.

Comment: `rand() % N + A` will give you a value in the range `[A, A + N[`, not `[A, N[`. What you want may be `rand() % (n - 2) + 2` for example

Comment: That's not a C or even programming question, but basic mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact formula that I use in my other program is:

```
i = min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1))
```

[Look here for other explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range)

Comment: I just do my duty

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, your range math is off.

You might find it useful to use a function to work the math out consistently each time. e.g.:

```
int RandInRange(int x0, int x1)
{
    if(x1<=x0) return x0;
    return rand() % (x1-x0+1) + x0;
}
```

then call it with what you want:

```
i = RandInRange(2,n);
k = RandInRange(i+2,n);
```