# c++ generating a double between 2 doubles

Tags: c++, random, double

So I need to randomly generate a double between 2 doubles, and in this specific case, it is to randomly generate a GPA.  I tried at first to do this:

```
srand(time(NULL));

double rands1 = rand() % (4) + ((rand() % (10)) / 10.0);
```

And this does work... mostly.  I can get anywhere from a 0.0 to 3.9, but it has to be from 0.0 to 4.0 inclusive! Changing the 4 in the code to a 5 can give 4.1 and higher as well however, and that is no good.

My question is, what would be a more efficient way to code this?  I apologize if there is a pretty straight forward answer/if this seems simple, but I am pretty new to coding and c++. Thank you!

Comment: Can you use C++11 features?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random integer from a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range)

Comment: You can always regard, 0.0 - 4.0 inclusive as the integers 0 to 40. Do the division after, when appropriate.

Comment: @WhiZTiM I can if I really need to, but am trying not to!

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe yup, by far the most efficient way to handle this problem. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just to find a gpa to one decimal place, you can find an int between 0 and 41 then divide by 10 to get a decimal.  For example:

```
double rand2 = (double)(rand()%41)/10;
```

rand()%41 will generate a number that is between 0 and 40 inclusive.  Then we cast it as a double and divide by 10.  So if the generated number is 34, we get 3.4 as a double.

To use other double as the range, you would just multiply them by the number of decimal places you want following the number, then also divide by that number

```
//Range== 0,34 with 3 decimal places    
double rand2 = (double)(rand()%35000)/1000;
```

Comment: this is definitely the easiest way for me to follow, I should've thought more about the actual math of it rather than try to have perfect code.  Thank you very much!!