# Clip random integer to a range of values without using division/modulo

Tags: c++

This can done this way:

```
int clamp(int rnd, int min, int max)
{
    return min + rnd % (max - min + 1);
}
```

Can this be done without using division?
Returned value doesn't necessarily have to match, however, uniform distribution has to be preserved.

`rnd`, `min`, and `max` are arbitrary integers. `rnd` in my case is a random integer.

One possible solution is to convert to `double` in range of `[0...1)` using [std::ldexp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ldexp) and then multiply, but I'd like to know if there is a simpler solution that doesn't involve floats and/or division.

Comment: Are you trying to a uniform int distribution with some given min and max? If yes, then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728404/3033441

Comment: If you can ensure that (max-min+1) is a perfect power of 2 then you can use `return min + rnd & (max - min)` because `n % pow(2, k) = n & (pow(2, k)-1)`

Comment: @LakshayGarg I updated the question. `min` and `max` are arbitrary, and I specified that uniformity has to be preserved, eg I cannot simply select some range of bits.

Comment: What about range of rnd? If that one is a power of 2 (say it's a full range of int), you can use shift instead of division

Comment: @LakshayGarg Seems like `uniform_int_distribution` "asks" rnd generator for a number in range of `[0... max - min + 1]` (at least that's what MS stdc++ lib does)

Comment: @isp-zax yes, rnd is full range 32 bits. How would shifting help? Shifting would work if the `[min... max]` range was `(X^2) -1`

Comment: Well, int is 16 bit and signed, not 32, but if your int is long, you can use (long long) cast instead of long, shift by 32 and scale like this min + (((long)max-(long)min) * (long)rnd)>>16 which effectively scales rnd to 0..1 and the value to min..max

Comment: @isp-zax int is 32 bits. I don't care what standard requires/guarantees, I care what's on practice. I updated my question with possible solution, I think what you mentioned should be similar but with fixed points and most likely should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If as per comment you have a 32 bit int and rnd input uniformly distributed between -2^31 and 2^31 you can calculate your output as `min + ((((long long)max-(long long)min) * (unsigned long)rnd))>>32` which effectively scales rnd to 0..1 and the value to min..max. Since you wrote you don't care about standards, I wasn't to particular about signed/unsigned conversion practices and warnings. Just gave a general idea - first multiply then shift instead of division.

```
int clamp(uint32_t rnd, int min, int max)
{
    return min + (1ull*rnd*(max - min + 1)) >> 32;
}
```