# Setting max and min values for creating a random number

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I am trying to generate random numbers between 2 and 11, here is my code:

```
srand(time(NULL));

int card;
card = rand() % 11 + 2;
```

However, currently my code is creating numbers from 2-12. How could I solve this so that it creates numbers from 2-11?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating random integer from a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range)

Comment: What you want is [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). And *please* stop using `rand()` in new code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range % 11` has 11 possible vales (0 to 10), but you want 10 possible values (2 to 11), so you first change your mod to `% 10`.  Next, since the values returned by `rand() % 10` start at 0, and you want to start at 2, add 2. So:

```
card = rand() % 10 + 2;
```

Comment: Using modulo introduces bias (look up the "pidgeon hole principle"). Better to use [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).